# Download and Save using scala\java

Tags: java, file, scala, url, web

I am trying to download and save a file from a web using the following code:

```
def readFileFromWeb = {

  val website = new URL("http://....")
  val rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
  val fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
  fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MaxValue);
}
```

It works for everything, but for the link i want to use it returns exception: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL
This url has special access promotions and has a message to choose read only - how can i download it anyways...?

Comment: What do you mean by downloading the website ?

Comment: HTTP Response code 400 means - `The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications. `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP response code: 400 for URL occurs when spaces appears in the url address - i encoded it into UTF-8 and it work great...